# Sending a message from background.js to a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message, transmission

I have a `background.js` with following snippet:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(toggleStatus);
```

Now inside `toggleStatus` I'd like to send a message to my content script, that something has happened. Is that possible?

Or am I completely missing the point, is this the right way to go?

Behind this is that I'd like to activate/deactive my extension, without the need of reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *some more* trial & error, I finally found a solution which satisfied me enough.

First add an event listener to the content script:

```
var extensionPort = chrome.extension.connect();

extensionPort.onMessage(function(msg) {
  // handle the received message
});
```

To send messages to every connected port of the extension add this to the `background.js`:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.postMessage({ someMessage: 'take me to the foobar' });
});
```